# How to download part of JavaScript code

Tags: firefox, wget, javascript, curl

I am looking at this website with a public table with some information I am interested in. I can download the info saving the page through Firefox, but it will take too much time to save all tables (I believe that there are more than four thousand draws), so I would like to automate the process.

I tried to get the info using curl and wget commands, but they don't bring more than the main HTML page, so I would like to know if there is a way/tool to download the piece of information that I am interested only (below more info): URL: https://www.playnow.com/lottery/lotto-649-winning-numbers/

Code:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="product-prize-breakdown__table-tr">
<td class="product-prize-breakdown_table-td">6/6</td>
<td class="product-prize-breakdown_table-td">$13,082,412.50</td>
<td class="product-prize-breakdown_table-td">0</td>
```

Thank you

Comment: Google "Selenium"

Answer (score 0):

The content is fetched via XHR in JSON format, this can be seen in the browsers developer tools.

E.g. https://www.playnow.com/services2/lotto/draw/six49/2022-07-02 will give you the data for the drawing of 2022-07-02 - nearly every language for further processing can deal with the JSON format.